# React Native release build is faling

Tags: reactjs, react-native

> **React native build is failing due to some dependencey**

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':react-native-community_checkbox:releaseRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.react:react-native:+.
     Required by:
         project :react-native-community_checkbox
      > Failed to list versions for com.facebook.react:react-native.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml'.
                  > Read timed out
```

Comment: JCenter and Bintray shut down today. many developers are facing this issue. meanwhile try some of the recommendations mentioned here in the open ticket for the issue https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35136

Comment: I am using mavenCentral still getting same error in my build.gradel still its downloading from jcenter i don't know why @duttasuraj

Comment: does you build.gradle file have any mention of `jcenter`. if so, comment it out. also there might be other packages inside your node_modules that might me using `jcenter`. if so, then there will be a problem too

Comment: and also the error mentions `Unable to load Maven meta-data from https...`. so definitely something must be using it

Comment: react-native-community_checkbox . I am using this package is it still using jcenter not sure ?